# tkinter postscript and save resizes canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, postscript, tkinter-canvas

I have a canvas that I would like to export with the same exact size as I specify in the code.
below is the function i use for this. asksaveasfile is a dialog window from tkinter:

```
    def print_grid(self):
        # a function for printing the grid with ghostscript
        self.canvas.postscript(file="grid.eps")
        from PIL import Image
        img = Image.open("grid.eps")

        fname = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".png")
        img.save(str(fname), "png")
```

I have two problems with this.

1. This resizes my original canvas to roughly its 75% size.
2. It seemingly adds extra pixels on the top and bottom that slightly screw with the aspect ratio of the new image.

Any guesses on why this is and how I could fix it?

Comment: I can't explain the resizing problem, but I would like to point out that `asksaveasfile()` is completely inappropriate here - it returns an *open file object*, which you are then extracting a filename from by manipulating its string representation - which is simply insane.  `asksaveasfilename()` gives you the chosen filename directly.

Comment: I'm presuming that you mean the resulting PNG file isn't the size you expected. You'd have to supply both grid.eps and the command line used to render to PNG with Ghostscript for me to be able to comment. At a rough guess, your command line doesn't specify -dEPSCrop so you are getting the default media size, but that's only a guess.

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks for that! fixed it!

Comment: @KenS I'm fairly new to python programming, how can i get this information, so i can share?  Indeed the problem is that i have a canvas off 800x500 and it exports a png of 604x380 (with the text rendered not legible due to poor quality)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer questions about tkinter or Python, because I know nothing about it :-( Presumably you could share the 'grid.eps' file, maybe someone can tell you how to find out what arguments are being passed to Ghostscript.